# A request just went to play.google.com/173.194.219.100 , is this a virus?

Tags: networking, security, virus

I had some google search tabs open
But no Android applications or the like.
Why was this request made?

(I'm sniffing traffic on my own machine0

Comment: That IP address is legitimately googles if you are concerned that the location is untrustworthy.

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks for the tip. I'm just confused what was calling it. I'm running OSX. No gmail.com window open. Slack, google searches and testing an iOS app. play.google.com is not something I expected from an encrypted.google.com search

Answer (score 0):

Why would a virus be contacting a Google server? That is surely just some automated check for application updates or the like.

This stuff is going to be happening regardless of any open apps. It will be happening at the OS level.

By the way, if you are concerned about data being sent off to Google's bit barns, you should not be using Android.

Comment: There are lots of reasons that malware might wish to connect to Google Play (there are some malicious packages there, and utilities an attacker may need). That in and of itself is no reason to suspect malfeasance, but its not appropriate to say that just because it points to google, that it must be ok.

Comment: @FrankThomas Hmm. Fair point I suppose.

Comment: I'm using MacOSX. I'm currently testing an iOS app. This is why tihs was surprising.

Comment: Why does your question mention android? Could the iOS app be using Google for some kind of authentication or ads?